# Python xlsx insert columns at cell location

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to copy data from a column and insert that data into another column at a specific cell location preserving the data above it, while shifting right the other column data.

I have been trying to do this in Openpyxl and with Pandas with no luck.
I'm attaching pictures of the desired outcome to help clarify the question.

**Before**:

[image: Before]

**After**:

[image: After]

--Updated with Code and output--

```
from openpyxl import *
def setupAfter():
    flag=False
    for cols in beforesheet.iter_cols():
        for cell in cols:
            if cell.row == 2 and cell.column == 2:
                aftersheet.insert_cols(cell.column, amount=1)
                flag=True
                break
        if flag:break
        else:
            continue
    aftersheet['B3'].value = beforesheet['A1'].value
    aftersheet['B4'].value = beforesheet['A2'].value
    aftersheet['B5'].value = beforesheet['A3'].value

outputwb = load_workbook(filename='aftertest.xlsx')
startwb = load_workbook(filename='beforetest.xlsx',keep_vba=True,data_only=True)
beforesheet = startwb.active
aftersheet = outputwb.active
setupAfter()
outputwb.save(filename=str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))+"_aftertest.xlsx")
```

[image: Script output]

Updated with functionality I'm trying to replicate in Excel:
[image: Excel Functionality]

Comment: Can you please share/add example code that you have written ?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editing_worksheets.html#moving-ranges-of-cells

Comment: @CharlieClark I have looked at the documentation however, it appears that most of the built in functionality will overwrite the data and not insert and left shift.

Comment: @KinaanKhanSherwani added code example for review

Comment: You shift left with negative values but it looks like you want to shift right. You will mess things up if you run any changes to the worksheet within an iter_cols or iter_rows loop.

Comment: @CharlieClark your correct, I want to insert data starting at a cell location row2 columnB, right shift the data from row2 down and insert the data in a new column.

Comment: So, why doesn't `ws.move_range()` work for you.

Comment: @CharlieClark I am trying to preserve the data already contained in the row and move_range() will overwrite the data.
I'm working with a weird file with alot of randomly placed tables within the sheet at different locations so preserving the data contained is important as well as preserving the data above the insert and below. Its an odd one I know.

Comment: Just extend the range to include any cells that might written over.

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have this dataframe:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

and you are trying to copy A[1:2] to C[1:2] like this:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   4
2   7   8   7
```

Here is how you do this:

```
df['c'].iloc[1:2] = df['a'].iloc[1:2]
```

Comment: thank you for the response but that doesnt quite work for my use case. I've updated the post with some additional code/images that better explain what I'm trying to accomplish.